# What is the regular expression to match any decimal in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

How would you write a regular expression to [match this C# Operator.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) I would like the user to be able to refine the amount as much as the language will allow.

Ex:

21589.69
1.45
385.4681

These are random examples I get from their data.

I tried:

```
\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?
\d(\.\d{1,3})?
```

These don't allow the level I need

I am trying to limit an MVC text box using the REGEX data annotation:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{1}(\.\d{1,3})?", ErrorMessage = "Must be valid number")]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `decimal.TryParse`?

Comment: @stuartd its for a web page. I am limiting an mvc text box for the values

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Comment: If you will put it as an answer I will accept, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) suggests `^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$` to match decimals, or `^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$` to also handle scientific notation.

Comment: Keep in mind that C# also allows numeric literals using scientific notation, such as `2e-18`.